# Regular expression to match text after another regex matched text

Tags: regex

In general, I would like to match a text with a pattern and match the text after that with another pattern. This sounds blurry I assume, so look at this example:

https://regex101.com/r/i35XhG/1

In the example I am matching for "Chassis ID   :" where I do not know the number of spaces between "Chassis ID" and ":", therefore I added \s+. The second capturing group matches a specially formatted series of hexadecimal numbers.
Now my goal is to isolate the hexadecimal part in the result but I only get that together with "Chassis ID   :". How can I accomplish this ?

This is a general problem for me to match something dynamic in length, but only care and retrieve what comes afterwards.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using php, or pcre? (Or something else?). There seem to be some flavours of regex that allow variable-length lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to wrap your capturing group into parenthesis, like:

```
(Chassis ID\s+: )()([0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+)
```

Now you can access `3c:61:04:65:22:80` by `\3`.

Look here: https://regex101.com/r/14vr2O/1 now you can see `Group 3.` with your value.

And also you may simplify your regex to this one:

```
(Chassis ID\s+: )((?:[0-9a-f]+:){5}[0-9a-f]+)
```

Comment: You can shorten that pattern to `(Chassis ID\s+: )()((?:[0-9a-f]+:){5}[0-9a-f]+)`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the empty group `()`?

Comment: Nothing :-), that is a mistake...
Thank you all

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Yes, true. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`(` and `)` create a capturing group in a regex Your first group is capturing `Chassis ID\s+:` and your second group is capturing nothing. Remove the `( and`) around `Chassis ID\s+:` and move the closing `)` of the second capturing group to the end of the regex. Now you can access `3c:61:04:65:22:80` by the first capturing group.

```
Chassis ID\s+: ([0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+:[0-9a-f]+)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was messing around too much to notice I left an empty capturing group in the expression